# re.split but leaving in the condition

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I have an example text string `text_var = 'ndTail7-40512-1'` and I want to split the first time I see a number followed by a - BUT I want to keep the number. Currently, I have `print(re.split('\d*(?=-)',text_var,1))` and my output is `['ndTail', '-40512-1']`. But I want to keep that number which is the trigger so it should look like `['ndTail', '7-40512-1']`. Any help?

Comment: `and I want to split when I see a number followed by a -` ... then shouldn't your expected output be `['ndTail', '7-4051', '2-1']` ?

Comment: add \d* inside braces: '(?=\d*-)'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my apologies, I updated the question with the correct wording. I only want the first one which is why I have the 1 conditional.

Comment: @Superior Yup, that worked. You should submit that as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here:

```
text_var = 'ndTail7-40512-1'
matches = re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d-.*$)', text_var)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
('ndTail', '7-40512-1')
```

Sometimes it can be easier to use `re.findall` rather than `re.split`.

The regex pattern used here says to:

```
(.*?)     match AND capture all content up to, but including
(\d-.*$)  the first digit which is followed by a hyphen;
          match and capture this content all the way to the end of the input
```

Note that we are using `re.findall` which typically has the potential to return multiple matches.  However, in this case, our pattern matches to the end of the input, so we are left with just a single tuple containing the two desired capture groups.

Comment: can you breakdown, or link a good tutorial, as to what's going on? I just started diving into regex today and It's all pretty confusing

Comment: @jon I added an explanation for the regex.  Beyond this, anything further would be out of scope for a single SO question.  You may review some good regex tutorial if anything else be unclear.